# when using docker run i get mv: cannot stat but it works if i use /bin/bash

Tags: docker

I need to move some files around and when i use the following command i get a `connot stat` error of move

```
docker run -v D:/PKS/potree/test/dist:/data1 -v D:/PKS/potree/test/tiles:/data2 -v D:/PKS/potree/test/tmp:/data3 oscar/mpc:v1 mv /data1/execution4/*/* /data1/tmp2 
mv: cannot stat '/data1/execution4/*/*': No such file or directory
```

if i instead run a `/bin/bash` and manually type the same `mv /data1/execution4/*/* /data1/tmp2` it works.

How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Davis to put my in the right direction.

The answer is to do as following instead:

```
docker run oscar/mpc:v1 /bin/bash -c "mv /data1/execution22/*/* /data1/out1/"
```

Answer (score 2):

The shell expands your wildcards (or doesn’t, because they match nothing) before ever running `docker`.  You’ll have to tell Docker to run a shell if you want wildcards expanded *inside* the container.